# Unexpected Behavior of Return Statement inside forEach() Loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, return, javascript-objects

My question relates to a JavaScript function I have written that seems to be behaving a bizarre way. In summary, the function execution seems to go on even after a `return` statement is encountered - it's as if the `return` statement inside a `forEach` loop is ignored. This is difficult to make sense of, and is not how it happens in any of the languages I have seen before.

Presenting a code snippet below - I have tried to make the code, logging and comments as focused and descriptive as possible so that the reader can easily identify the issue. However, I am sharing a detailed description of the problem as well if you'd prefer not to jump to the code directly.

In the code I have shared, the function `substituteWithMainColor()` takes a string value named `color` as argument. It matches it against each element of an array (called `substitutionArray`) of object literals, where each such object contains a member string called `mainColor`  and member array called `variations`. If the function finds the `color` argument in any of the `variations` arrays, then it returns the corresponding `mainColor` of the object in which the match was found. If no match is found in any of the objects, then the function returns the original value passed as argument.

In my example, an argument **"Cyan"** is passed to the function `substituteWithMainColor()`. Since the array `substitutionArray` contains **"Cyan"** as one of the strings in the `variations` array of its third item, a match is found ( and the logs show it). However, at this point, instead of returning with the matched `mainColor` value **"Blue"** as expected, the function ignores the `return` statement inside the `forEach()` loop and keeps on executing further iterations of the `forEach` loop (the logs show this, too). Eventually it executes the final `return` statement which is after the `forEach()` loop, and returns the original `color` value, which is erroneous.

Can someone please help me understand what might be going on?

```js
 const substitutionArray = [
            { mainColor: "Red", variations: ["Magenta", "Orange", "Crimson", "Coral", "Maroon"] },
            { mainColor: "Blue", variations: ["Purple", "Violet", "Cyan"] },
            { mainColor: "Green", variations: ["Teal", "Lime", "Aquamarine", "Olive"] }
        ]

        function substituteWithMainColor(color) {
            logToPage(`In substituteWithMainColor() function. Input: ${color}`);
            substitutionArray.forEach(item => {
                logToPage(`Testing input ${color} against variations of ${item.mainColor}`)
                if (item.variations.includes(color)) {
                    logToPage(`FOUND MATCH for ${color} - Main color: ${item.mainColor}. Returning ${item.mainColor}`);
                    return item.mainColor;  //Function should return from here if match is found.
                }
            });
            logToPage(`No matches found for ${color}. Returning ${color}`)
            return color;    //No matches found
        }

        function writeToPage(text) { document.body.innerHTML += `<div class = "content"> ${text} </div>`; }
        function logToPage(text) { document.body.innerHTML += `<div class = "log"> ${text} </div >`; }

        const colorName = "Cyan";
        writeToPage(`Original Color: ${colorName}`)
        writeToPage(`Returned Value: ${substituteWithMainColor(colorName)}`);   // "Blue should be returned"
```

```css
        .content {
            outline: 1px solid rgb(161, 189, 135);
            padding: 5px;
            margin: 5px;
            color: rgb(255, 127, 80);
            font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .log {
            outline: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding: 5px;
            margin: 5px;
            color: rgb(85, 91, 122);
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
        }
```

Comment: The return statement in the callback function of `forEach` returns from that callback only, and the value is ignored, it is not used anywhere.

Comment: Such a simple explanation - how could I not realize that it was returning from a callback? Appreciate your reply - would you like to make it a formal answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `forEach` is not the same an a normal `for` loop. You're essentially passing a function to be executed every loop, so your `return` acts in the scope *of that function*, not the loop.

It's a little like this:

```
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    foo();
}

function foo() {
    // do something
    return true;
}
```

You're probably looking for something like `find()` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```
substitutionArray.find(item => item.variations.includes(color)).mainColor;
```

Note that the return of the `find` it the `item` inside `substitutionArray`, so you have to extract the `mainColor` afterwards. If there's a chance that you won't find it, add a null check

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Apart from understanding the error in my code, I was able to learn about and apply the find() method. Appreciated.